# How to save List<String> to SharedPreferences in kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences

In my project, I have a list of String.
I want to save this List to shared preferences.
Any one can help?

```
data class select(
    @SerializedName("items")
    var items: MutableList<String>?=null
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Comment: I need kotlin description..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can store list as Json Text in SharedPreference using Gson and then work accordingly

```
//saving list in Shared Preference
    fun setLists(list:ArrayList<String>){
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(list)//converting list to Json
        editor.putString("LIST",json)
        editor.commit()
    }
    //getting the list from shared preference
    fun getList():ArrayList<String>{
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = preferences.getString("LIST",null)
        val type = object :TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.type//converting the json to list
        return gson.fromJson(json,type)//returning the list
    }
```

Don't forget to implement the Gson library in your app level gradle file